# Rsync over ssh with key gets error EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, rsync

I can ssh into my EC2 with:

```
ssh -i /Users/User/Downloads/key.pem ubuntu@ec2-myec2.amazonaws.com
```

My directory:

```
/A
   /B
      /folderToTransfer
```

I can rsync into the same directory with:

```
rsync -avrz -e “ssh -i /Users/User/Downloads/key.pem”   / 
/Users/User/Documents/Programming/A/B/folderToTransfer  /
ubuntu@ec2-myec2.amazonaws.com
```

New directory:

```
/A
   /B
      /folderToTransfer
      /ubuntu@ec2-myec2.amazonaws.com
```

But this fails (when adding :~/ to the end)

```
rsync -avrz -e “ssh -i /Users/User/Downloads/key.pem”   / 
/Users/User/Documents/Programming/A/B/folderToTransfer  /
ubuntu@ec2-myec2.amazonaws.com:~/
```

With the error

```
rsync: Failed to exec ?\#200\#234ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/pipe.c(86) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Others don't seem to have this same problem when rsyncing with ssh -i, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rsync -avrz -e “ssh -i /Users/User/Downloads/key.pem”   / 
               ^                                    ^
```

You're not using the ASCII double quote character `"` here. You're using some kind of open- and close-quote characters intended for typesetting. Your command is failing because the shell doesn't treat these characters as quote marks; rsync ends up trying to execute a program named `“ssh`.

Replace the characters with ASCII double quotes:

```
rsync -avrz -e "ssh -i /Users/User/Downloads/key.pem"   /
```

Answer (score 2):

**The AWS ec2 solutions (with keys) below work for me only with a good formatting of the command line**

- solution 1

`rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/xxxxxx.pem" ec2-user@xxxxxx.com:/var/www/ /var/www/copywww/`

- solution 2

`rsync -avrz -e " ssh -i  /root/xxxxxx.pem " ec2-user@xxxxx.com:/var/www/  /var/www/copywww`